# Constructing a 5-dimensional injective function

Tags: functions

I am trying to find a 5-dimensional injective function, any suggestions or any ideas as to how I can construct one? Formally I am looking for a function $f: \mathbb{R}^5 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ which is injective.

Comment: Iterlacing the digits will give you an bijective function from $\mathbb R_+^5 \to \mathbb R_+$  And you can compose with bijective functions from $\mathbb R\to \mathbb R_+$ and back again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First we construct an injective function $\mathbb{R}^2\rightarrow \mathbb{R}.$ To simplify matters, it suffices to construct an injective function $(0,1)\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ since $\tan(\pi (x-\frac{1}{2}))$ is a bijection $(0,1)\rightarrow \mathbb{R}.$

Given a pair of real numbers $(a,b)\in(0,1)^2$ they have unique binary representations $a = \sum_{i=0}^{\infty}\frac{a_i}{2^i}$ and $b = \sum_{i=0}^{\infty}\frac{b_i}{2^i}$ with neither $(a_i)$ nor $(b_i)$ ending in an infinite tail of $1$'s.  Then it's not hard to see that the map sending $(a,b)$ to $0.a_1 b_1 a_2 b_2 \ldots$ (written in binary) is an injective map $(0,1)^2\rightarrow (0,1).$  Notice that this decimal will not end in infinite sequence of $1$'s by construction.

Now by identifying $\mathbb{R}^5$ with $\mathbb{R}^2\times \mathbb{R}^3,$ we obtain an injective map $\mathbb{R}^5\rightarrow \mathbb{R}\times \mathbb{R}^3 = \mathbb{R^4}.$  Similarly, we have injective maps $\mathbb{R}^4\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^3$, $\mathbb{R}^3\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^2$, and $\mathbb{R}^2\rightarrow \mathbb{R}.$ By composing these maps we get an injection $\mathbb{R}^5\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ as desired.